# Can not connect to admin page on django 3.0.7

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I just installed django and when I go to log onto the admin page the runserver stops running and the only error that pops up is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The virtual environment is active and running, and I can not find any answers online.

Comment: firewall issues?

Comment: no ive been looking for a day now and one of the things im reading is it could be a bug in python but I'm not sure I just started using django

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Django 3.0.5
What is your current python version? I had 3.7 and had to upgrade to 3.8 to be able to load the admin page. Had this issue before and downgrading to an older version of Django also works. Keep in mind if you upgrade the python version you will need to update your virtual env.